# No GPS on Alcatel 1T 7

Tags: tablet, gps, here-maps

Before I bought this tablet, I have been exploring about it on internet, and found on GSMArena that it has built in GPS.

[image: IMG:]

On Alcatel official site it also says that it has built-in GPS

[image: IMG:]

But when I try to start navigation with HERE WeGo app, app doesn't allow to start navigation because GPS isn't turned on.

[image: IMG:]

But in settings it is set to "High accuracy", which means that tablet uses GPS, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth.. to better determine location.

[image: IMG:]

Does anyone had same problem or does anyone know solution?

Btw. I am sorry because language on tablet is set to Serbian, but I translated what is important.

Comment: The red box for the specs say `GPS (LATAM Version Only)`. What version/model number do you have?

Comment: Model: 8068, Android: 8.1.0, Kernel: 3.18.79, Build number: 01003. And what does LATAM mean?

Comment: LATAM means Latin America, so for devices for sale to that region it will have GPS. However all I can find the Model 9009G - Alcatel 1T 7 3G. I would see if Google Maps gives you accurate location, and check if HERE WeGo has all the permissions granted. My fear is that the `Yes with A-GPS` from GSM Arena implies that the 9009G would need a sim/data plan for use, see: [Assisted GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)

Comment: It is not 3G version, it just has Wi-Fi. And HERE WeGo has all the permissions that it needs, so does that mean that this device doesn't have GPS even if there is setting for enabling it in settings?

Comment: Correct. If Google Maps Go gets a reasonable fix, it may be due to their large collection of WiFi locations. Other tablets have GPS so can take a while to get a fix (even offline), but if the tablet doesn't have a GPS chip, all you can get is coarse location.